# Windows Phone Trace Running Events

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, trace, windows-phone, windows-phone-7-emulator

How can i trace the running events while in debug mode, during application life  cycle in windows phone, is it possible to see which events are fired?

Comment: If you're talking about the events within your application, you could try debugging the event handlers. If the respective delegate is called, then I'd say the event was fired.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah really easy, in every method you have just add the following

```
Debug.WriteLine("Hit (Method Name) for (Page).xaml");
```